# Allergy test for specific allergens

Tags: allergy

Let's say I order an allergy blood test. The test will, for example, test for White Oak (Quercus alba). Would a positive result for that specific allergen indicate, broadly speaking, a hypersensitivity to a similar tree in the same genus (for example, Quercus coccinea)?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. However, have you done any prior research about it? If so, please share that here. Thank you!

Comment: For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?